# Android - Service and application communication

Tags: java, android, service, websocket

I have a WebsocketRequest singleton class which works perfectly in my application, when I receive a response from server I send a broadcast for Activities and Fragments which are listenning.

Now my problem is I want to launch once a background service which manages my websocket's calls.

I already try to create a Binder for my service in my "Custom Application", but it doesn't work, I think Binder is designed to Activity.

Anyone has an idea on how can communicate my application with service and service with application ?

Thx in advance

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: I think I resolve my issue, I send a broadcast to my service which makes websocket call. Then my service send another broadcast to my application.

Comment: Is sending too many broadcast can cause problems ?

Comment: no but u need to check that your broad cast receiver not broken. this is the way to communicate with Activity and services.

Comment: Ando, how can I check if a broadcast receiver is not broken ?